# Any way to set access-control-allow-origin for a windows azure blob

Tags: azure-storage

I am storing json blobs on azure which I am accessing via XHR. While trying to load these blobs I am getting this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myjsoncontainer/myblob.json?json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there any way to set the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header of a blob returned by azure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Windows Azure Storage added CORS support on November 26, 2013: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Support for the Windows Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn535601.aspx). More details and C#/JavaScript samples - [Windows Azure Storage: Introducing CORS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx).

The CORS options can be set on a storage account using the Windows.Azure.Storage client library version 3.0.1.0 or later, available from NuGet, using something similar to the following pseudocode:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
          "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ABC;AccountKey=XYZ");
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();

serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();

serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule() {
    AllowedHeaders = { "..." },
    AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head,
    AllowedOrigins = { "..." },
    ExposedHeaders = { "..." },
    MaxAgeInSeconds = 600
});

blobClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not currently but Scott Hanselman, Program Manager for Azure, has [confirmed support for this is coming soon](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2850796-support-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-via-a) on Feb 4th 2013.

Answer (score 2):

One of the helpful [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx)
it might help you all.

The code which I was missing was

```
private static void ConfigureCors(ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
{
    serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
    serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
    {
        AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
        AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
        AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
        ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
        MaxAgeInSeconds = 1800 // 30 minutes
     });
}
```

It basically add some rules to SAS Url, and I am able to upload my files to blob.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, they **still** haven't added this.  You can set up a proxy on an Amazon EC2 instance that fetches the objects on the Azure CDN, then returns the data with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, which allows you to make the requests through our proxy. You can also temporarily cache stuff on the proxy to help with speed/performance (this solution obviously takes a hit there), but it's still not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

The idea is that you define a callback function on your site that will receive the JSON content, and your JSON document becomes a JavaScript file the invokes your callback with the desired data. [[Thomas Conté](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2011/08/10/accessing-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-jquery.aspx), August 2011]

To do this, create a document that wraps your JSON content in a JavaScript function call:

```
{ "key": "value", ... }
```

becomes

```
myFunc({ "key": "value", ... });
```

Now you're not loading JSON but JavaScript, and `script` tags are not subject to Single Origin Policy. jQuery provides [convenient methods for loading JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myjsoncontainer/myblob.jsonp?jsonp',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'myFunc',
    success: function (data) {
        // 'data' now has your JSON object already parsed
        // and converted to a JavaScript object.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While jsonp works, I wouldn't recommend it. Read the first comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076449/763167) for specifics.  I think the best way around this is to use CORS.  Unfortunately, Azure doesn't support this.  So if you can, I would change storage providers to one that does ([Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started) for example)